Is there someone better than Yunus bin Matta?
I came across this hadith where rasulAllah saw said that he doesn't say that anybody is better than Yunus Bin matta. Does the statement of RasulAllah saw exclude himself or not?
The hadith goes like this :
Sahih al-Bukhari 3414, 3415
Narrated Abu Huraira:

'Once while a Jew was selling something, he was offered a price that he was not pleased with. So, he said, "No, by Him Who gave Moses
superiority over all human beings!" Hearing him, an Ansari man got up
and slapped him on the face and said, "You say: By Him Who Gave Moses
superiority over all human beings although the Prophet (Muhammad) is
present amongst us!" The Jew went to the Prophet and said, "O
Abu-l-Qasim! I am under the assurance and contract of security, so
what right does so-and-so have to slap me?" The Prophet (ﷺ) asked the
other, "Why have you slapped". He told him the whole story. The
Prophet (ﷺ) became angry, till anger appeared on his face, and said,
"Don't give superiority to any prophet amongst Allah's Prophets, for
when the trumpet will be blown, everyone on the earth and in the
heavens will become unconscious except those whom Allah will exempt.
The trumpet will be blown for the second time and I will be the first
to be resurrected to see Moses holding Allah's Throne. I will not know
whether the unconsciousness which Moses received on the Day of Tur has
been sufficient for him, or has he got up before me. And I do not say
that there is anybody who is better than Yunus bin Matta."

Jazak'Allahu kahyran
